# newFixedThreadPool() vs newCachedThreadPool()

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

In case `newCachedThreadPool()` as per creates a thread pool that creates new threads as needed, but will reuse previously constructed threads when they are available whereas in case of `newFixedThreadPool(int size)` specify size to create the thread pool with size specified.

Why isn't`newFixedThreadPool(int size)` implemented in `newCachedThreadPool()` fashion where thread pool creates the new thread only when required and will limit the thread to size?

Any clarrification on the above is really helpful.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949355/newcachedthreadpool-v-s-newfixedthreadpool

Comment: Because that would not be a **fixed** thread pool anymore. The created thread pools are both instances of ThreadPoolExecutor, created with different options. Creating an starting a new thread takes some time, and you might want that time to be taken at startup, rather than when submitting a new task.

Comment: @JBNizet Will it not hold the resources in case of fixed thread pool. Its the decision between which is more costlier. Any insight on it.

Comment: If you know you'll need a certain number of threads, it's less overhead to create them at the outset, and fail-fast if you can't, rather than doing all the bookkeeping necessary to expire unused threads or determine whether create more threads.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`newFixedThreadPool` also creates threads lazily. Try this test:

```
    ThreadPoolExecutor p = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    System.out.println(p.getPoolSize());
    p.execute(new Runnable() {public void run() {}});
    System.out.println(p.getPoolSize());
```

The differences are:

1. `newFixedThreadPool`'s threads never expire, while `newCachedThreadPool`'s threads expire 60 secs after last used
2. `newCacheThreadPool`'s maximum number of active threads is unlimited