# Executors out of memory

Tags: android, out-of-memory, executorservice

I'm trying to scan my local network to find a device with a specifi opened port.

When i do the scan 6-7 times i take an out of memory.

```
 WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    int ipAddress = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress();
    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") String localIp = String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d",
            (ipAddress & 0xff),
            (ipAddress >> 8 & 0xff),
            (ipAddress >> 16 & 0xff),
            (ipAddress >> 24 & 0xff));

    String s = ServerUtilities.findServerIp(localIp);
```

The findIpAdressFunction :

```
public static String findServerIp(String localIp) {
    final String functionName = "findServerIp";
    final String[] serverIp = {""};
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String prefix = localIp.substring(0, localIp.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    ConfigManager.printLog(functionName, "Started", AppConfig.LOG_TYPE_DEBUG);

    if (localIp.length() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
            final String testIp = prefix + String.valueOf(i);
            Executors.newCachedThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(testIp);
                        checkInetAddress(inetAddress);
                    } catch (ConnectException e) {
                        if (e.toString().contains("ECONNREFUSED"))
                            ConfigManager.printLog(functionName, "Wrong server : connection refused", AppConfig.LOG_TYPE_VERBOSE);
                        else
                            ConfigManager.printLog(functionName, "Error : " + e.toString() + "\n\tip=" + testIp, AppConfig.LOG_TYPE_ERROR);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        ConfigManager.printLog(functionName, "Error scanning network : " + e.toString() + "\n\tip=" + testIp, AppConfig.LOG_TYPE_ERROR);
                    }
                }

                private void checkInetAddress(InetAddress inetAddress) throws IOException {
                    if (inetAddress.isReachable(500)) {
                        ConfigManager.printLog(functionName, "Testing " + testIp, AppConfig.LOG_TYPE_DEBUG);
                        new Socket(testIp, AppConfig.SERVER_PORT_CLIENT);
                        new Socket(testIp, AppConfig.SERVER_PORT_DOWNLOAD);
                        serverIp[0] = testIp;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    } else {
        ConfigManager.printLog(functionName, "Error\n\tlocal IP is null or empty : " + localIp, AppConfig.LOG_TYPE_ERROR);
    }

    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    ConfigManager.printLog(functionName,
            "Task finished\n\tresult : \"" + serverIp[0] + "\"\n\telapsed time : " + String.valueOf(endTime - startTime) + " (ms)"
            , AppConfig.LOG_TYPE_INFO);
    return serverIp[0];
}
```

**the logcat error :**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.sanilea.speedclientserverside, PID: 23369
                                                                                   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (stack size 16384 bytes) failed: Try again
                                                                                       at java.lang.VMThread.create(Native Method)
                                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1029)
                                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:920)
                                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1338)
                                                                                       at com.sanilea.speedclientserverside.utility.ServerUtilities.findServerIp(ServerUtilities.java:163)
                                                                                       at com.sanilea.speedclientserverside.activities.ConnexionActivity.scanAvailableNetwork(ConnexionActivity.java:96)
                                                                                       at com.sanilea.speedclientserverside.activities.ConnexionActivity.access$000(ConnexionActivity.java:42)
                                                                                       at com.sanilea.speedclientserverside.activities.ConnexionActivity$1.onClick(ConnexionActivity.java:64)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4508)
                                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18675)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                                                                                       at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The error is with the executorService bun i don't know why...

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new thread pool for each IP.

You should call `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` outside of the for loop and store its result in a variable. Then call `Execute` on that variable inside the loop.

Comment: i also tried with like this :

`
        ExecutorService executorService =  Executors.newCachedThreadPool() ;

        if (localIp.length() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
                final String testIp = prefix + String.valueOf(i);
                executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
`

Comment: and, also, use a fixed size executor or you'll clug the device

Comment: @eduyayo +1. I thought maybe `newCachedThreadPool` might have a hard limit, but this thread indicates the opposite https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949355/java-newcachedthreadpool-versus-newfixedthreadpool

Answer (score 0):

i just add : executorService.shutdownNow(); and it's resolved