# Error on pi value using the Gregory-Leibniz with thread parameter

Tags: java, multithreading

Im trying to implement the Gregory-Leibniz  in Java using multi threads and specifying the number of threads to use. I failing because in the end PI is giving me value of 43.

Can anyone give me an hand please? I would be fine if i didnt haveto inut the number of threads, but inputing the number of threads is ruining my program and not sure how to solve this.

```
    System.out.print("Insert Number of threads:");
    int numetothreads = scannerObj.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Nº threads : " + numetothreads);
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949355/executors-newcachedthreadpool-versus-executors-newfixedthreadpool
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numetothreads);
    long ti = System.currentTimeMillis();


    //separate in 4 and join after
    Future<Double> parte1 = es.submit(new CarlzParalel(1, 100000000));
    Future<Double> parte2 = es.submit(new CarlzParalel(100000001, 200000000));
    Future<Double> parte3 = es.submit(new CarlzParalel(200000001, 300000000));
    Future<Double> parte4 = es.submit(new CarlzParalel(400000001, 500000000));
```

This is what im using to specify the number of threads

```
public class CarlzParalel implements Callable<Double> {

    private int begin;
    private int end;

    public CarlzParalel(int begin, int end) {
        this.begin= begin;
        this.end = end;
    }

    public Double call() throws Exception {
        double sum = 0.0;
        double fator;
        for (int i = begin; i <= end; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                fator = Math.pow(1.0, i + 1);
            } else {
                fator = Math.pow(1.0, -i + 1);
            }
            sum += fator / (2.0 * (double) i - 1.0);
        }

        return sum;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        //cria um pool de threads para realizar o cálculo
        Scanner scannerObj = new Scanner(System.in);

        //System.out.println("Nº threads : " + listathreads);
        //ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        System.out.print("Insert number of threads:");
        int numetothreads = scannerObj.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Nº threads : " + numetothreads);
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949355/executors-newcachedthreadpool-versus-executors-newfixedthreadpool
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numetothreads);
        long ti = System.currentTimeMillis();


        //separate in 4 then join all
        Future<Double> parte1 = es.submit(new CarlzParalel(1, 100000000));
        Future<Double> parte2 = es.submit(new CarlzParalel(100000001, 200000000));
        Future<Double> parte3 = es.submit(new CarlzParalel(200000001, 300000000));
        Future<Double> parte4 = es.submit(new CarlzParalel(400000001, 500000000));

        /*
        Future<Double> parte1 =  es.submit(new CarlzParalel(1,100000000));
        Future<Double> parte2 = es.submit(new CarlzParalel(100000001,200000000));
        Future<Double> parte3 = es.submit(new CarlzParalel(200000001,300000000));
        Future<Double> parte4 = es.submit(new CarlzParalel(300000001,400000000));*/

        //join the values
        double pi = 4.0 * (parte1.get() + parte2.get() + parte3.get() + parte4.get());

        es.shutdown();

        System.out.println("Pi is " + pi);
        long tf = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long tcc = tf-ti;
        System.out.println("Time with concurrency " + tcc);

        ti = System.currentTimeMillis();

        //separate in 4 then join all without concurrency

        try {
            Double parteA = (new CarlzParalel(1, 100000000)).call();
            Double parteB = (new CarlzParalel(100000001, 200000000)).call();
            Double parteC = (new CarlzParalel(200000001, 300000000)).call();
            Double parteD = (new CarlzParalel(400000001, 500000000)).call();
            pi = 4.0 * (parteA + parteB + parteC + parteD);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //join them all

        System.out.println("PI is " + pi);
        tf = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long tsc = tf - ti;
        double divisao = (double) tcc / (double) tsc;
        double gain = (divisao) * 100;
        System.out.println("Time with no concurrency " + tsc);
        System.out.println("Gain % – TCC/TSC * 100 = " + gain + " %");
        System.out.println("Number of processores: " + Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());


    }
}
```

```
Insert number of threads:4
Nº threads : 4
Pi is 43.41189321992768
Time wasted with concurrency 10325
Pi is 43.41189321992768
Time wasted without concurrecy 42131
gainz% – TCC/TSC * 100 = 24.506895160333247 %
Nº threads: 4
```

Comment: if you "combine" futures shouldn't you divide to get the average of these 4 values?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are trying to calculate the formula:

[image]

Then your summing method looks incorrect.

The numerator code you have will always return 1. If you are trying to get it to return 1 or -1 there are several ways you can do it such as:

```
   double numerator = n % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1;
```

The denominator also looks wrong to me, I would probably favour something like:

```
   double denominator = n * 2 + 1;
```

And as you are starting with 1 rather than 0, the `for` loop would need to be modified to subtract 1 from the input parameters. All together the method would look as follows:

```
    public Double call() throws Exception {
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int i = begin - 1; i < end; i++) {
            double numerator = i % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1;
            double denominator = i * 2 + 1;
            sum += numerator / denominator;
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

However

1. Your inputs are missing the range from 300000001 to 400000000
2. double isn't really suitable for any sort of precision. Out of the box you could use `BigDecimal` but it will obviously be at least a factor slower.

With regard to precision and doubles, I wouldn't be surprised if the results of below are different:

```
    double pi = 4.0 * (parte1.get() + parte2.get() + parte3.get() + parte4.get());
    System.out.println("Pi is " + pi);


    // reverse the order of the sum
    double 4.0 * (parte4.get() + parte3.get() + parte2.get() + parte1.get());
    System.out.println("Pi is " + pi);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Going to try to improve my code, BigDecimal looks like a good idea because i need bigger intervals. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is wrong with your math in `call` but that is certainly where the issue is.

```
public static class CarlzParallel implements Callable<Double> {

    private int begin;
    private int end;

    public CarlzParallel(int begin, int end) {
        this.begin = begin;
        this.end = end;
    }

    public Double call() throws Exception {
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int i = begin; i <= end; i++) {
            double dividend = (i % 2) == 0 ? -1 : 1;
            double divisor = (2 * i) - 1;
            sum += dividend / divisor;
        }
        return sum;
    }

}

private void test() {
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    //separate in 4 then join all
    Future<Double> parte1 = es.submit(new CarlzParallel(1, 100000000));
    Future<Double> parte2 = es.submit(new CarlzParallel(100000001, 200000000));
    Future<Double> parte3 = es.submit(new CarlzParallel(200000001, 300000000));
    Future<Double> parte4 = es.submit(new CarlzParallel(400000001, 500000000));
    double π = 0;
    try {
        es.shutdown();
        while(!es.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            System.out.println("Waiting ...");
        }
        π = 4.0 * (parte1.get() + parte2.get() + parte3.get() + parte4.get());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(π);
}
```

prints

```
3.141592650755993
```